# reflection between java versions

Tags: java, maven, package, javac, backwards-compatibility

Let’s say that in hypothetical Java version X.1 we have a class in the standard library (or third-party with backwards compatible API and version tied to Java version)

```
public class String {
    private final byte[] bytes;
    //...
}
```

and in Java X.2 it has changed internally

```
public class String {
    private final char[] chars;
    //...
}
```

We also have a class that accesses String class field, which is a part of a plugin for a server

```
public class Accessor {
    public static Field getField() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        return String.class.getDeclaredField(“bytes”);
}
```

Server runs on Java X.2, plugin was compiled using Java X.1 and loaded at runtime

What will happen? Which String class will the Accessor see? If it will be X.1 then what happens if server and plugin share a String?
If it will be X.2 is there a way to force a specific version at compile-time or in the package configuration, or at least determine from which Java version the currently visible String class comes from?

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about java.lang.String class or any other class from jvm then it is usually a part of a JVM where the code is run. And in your case you'll get version x.2.

But if we talk about custom compiled class from a 3rd party library then it depends on the target version that was specified during compilation of that class. In your case it might be version 1.x.

Comment: But how then the JVM handles a String that is shared between a plugin (or 3rd part library) with target version X.1 and server X.2

Comment: When compiled the class doesn't store information about other classes that it depends on, only package name and class name. Therefore in runtime they will both use a version provided by jvm. And in your case there will be an exception in runtime saying that there's no such member in class String.

Comment: There's also one more way to load multiple classes with the same name and package but with different versions. But for that part you'll need to introduce a new class loader in your application for each individual plugin. It is the way how Application servers like tomcat, jboss, glassfish and many other work. The most popular way to implement such thing is to use osgi.

Comment: @AzamatZhurtbayev but using different loaders for different versions only works with the 3rd party libraries. You can’t load different versions of `java.lang.String`.

Comment: @Holger I think it is not impossible but yes, very very difficult. In the worst scenario just to implement your own JVM :) However, I think it is possible to load custom rt.jar from a different JVM.

Comment: No, a JVM doesn’t allow two versions of the class `java.lang.String` in general. Otherwise, it wouldn’t a a JVM.